# How to convert jquery boilerplate into require boilerplate?

Tags: jquery, requirejs

How can I convert or put jquery namespace plugin into require boilerplate? For intstance,

This is my standard jquery boilerplate usually,

```
// A namepace structure:
(function($){

    // Initial setting.
    var pluginName = 'BR_account';
    var storageName = 'plugin_' + pluginName;

    var methods = {

        init : function( options ) {
            console.log("this is a jquery plugin boilerplate in requirejs boilerplate"); // nothing returned.
        }
    };

    $.fn[pluginName] = function( method ) {

        if ( methods[method] ) {
            return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
            return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );  // always change 'init' to something else if you different method name.
        } else {
            $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.' + pluginName + '.' );
        }
        return this; 
    };

    $.fn[pluginName].defaults = {
        onSuccess: function() {}
    };

})(jQuery);
```

And this is the require boilerplate usually,

```
//Filename: boilerplate.js
define([
    // These are path alias that we configured in our bootstrap
    'jquery', // lib/jquery/jquery
    'underscore', // lib/underscore/underscore
    'backbone' // lib/backbone/backbone
], function($, _, Backbone){
    // Above we have passed in jQuery, Underscore and Backbone
    // They will not be accessible in the global scope
    return {};
    // What we return here will be used by other modules
});
```

But how can I mix them together - or maybe I shouldn't??

This is my test,

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone'
], function($, _, Backbone){

    console.log(Backbone); // I get an object of Backbone


    // A namepace structure:
    (function($){

        // Initial setting.
        var pluginName = 'BR_account';
        var storageName = 'plugin_' + pluginName;

        var methods = {

            init : function( options ) {
                console.log("this is a jquery plugin boilerplate in requirejs boilerplate"); // nothing returned.
            }
        };

        $.fn[pluginName] = function( method ) {

            if ( methods[method] ) {
                return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
            } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
                return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );  // always change 'init' to something else if you different method name.
            } else {
                $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.' + pluginName + '.' );
            }
            return this; 
        };

        $.fn[pluginName].defaults = {
            onSuccess: function() {}
        };

    })(jQuery);


});
```

It is not working of course. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an [example](https://github.com/mangalam-research/wed/blob/master/lib/wed/jquery.findandself.js) that works with or without RequireJS:

```
(function (factory) {
    // If in an AMD environment, define() our module, else use the
    // jQuery global.
    'use strict';
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd)
        define(['jquery'], factory);
    else
        factory(jQuery);
}(function ($) {
    'use strict';

    // This is the plugin proper.
    $.fn.findAndSelf = function(selector) {

        var $nodes = this.find(selector);

        if (this.is(selector))
            $nodes = $nodes.add(this);

        return $nodes;
    };
}));
```

The way this works is that the glue function (the first function in the code) is invoked with a factory function as its only parameter. The factory function only needs to get a reference to jQuery. The glue function detect whether an AMD environment (which RequireJS is) is present. If so, it requires the `jquery` module and passes that as the jQuery reference. If not, it acts the same way a non-AMD-aware plugin does.