# Uglified define not defining

Tags: javascript, requirejs, r.js

I'm using r.js to uglify and concat my js files. Some of the functions appear in the uglified file, like so (NB. This is beautified for readability):

```
!function(root, factory) {
if ("object" == typeof exports) {
    {
        var backbone = require("backbone");
        require("marionette");
    }
    dust = require("dust");
    module.exports = factory(backbone, dust);
} else if ("function" == typeof define && define.amd) {
    define("marionette-dust", [ "backbone", "dust", "marionette" ], factory);
    console.log(requirejs.s.contexts._.config);
}
}(this, function(Backbone, dust) {
    alert("in");
    Backbone.Marionette.Renderer.render = function(template, data) {
        console.log("BBD: ", arguments);
        var html;
        console.log("dust: ", dust);
        dust.render(template, data, function(err, out) {
            console.log("out", out);
            html = out;
        });
        return html;
    };
    console.log("Backbone", Backbone);
});
```

If I load the page and then test with:

```
require.defined("marionette-dust")
```

then it comes back as not loaded. If I put break points in then basically it goes into the amd part (the else-if block) and define is present, yet it doesn't define and the factory part is never executed...

To be clear: the first console log shows the requirejs object (without the module loaded); none of the others are executed because they are in the factory function... I've been working at it for a few hours now and I think this is to do with wrappers being converted in r.js The require.defined is something I type myself afterwards in to test if the module has been defined - it comes back false...

Repo is available at: https://github.com/jmsherry/birds2 if you want to look more closely

Any help greatly appreciated...

Comment: Please update your question to show what the output of your `console.log` statements is, and when they occur relative to your `require.defined` call.

Comment: Hi @Louis, the first console log shows the requirejs object (without the module loaded); none of the others are executed because they are in the factory function...

I've been working at it for a few hours now and I think this is to do with wrappers being converted in r.js

The require.defined is something I type myself afterwards in to test if the module has been defined - it comes back false...

Comment: You should put your answer to the question I asked in my previous comment into the body of your question rather than in a comment. Comments are ephemeral, and easily overlooked by readers. Regarding wrappers, in and of themselves wrappers are not a problem with `r.js`. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20349888/1906307) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21352190/1906307), for instance.

Comment: I think I'm using the shim wrongly. I've got stuff in there that can be used without it, like jquery, etc. When it comes to using r.js I'm getting odd results, eg. I have a script full of dust templates (they're just self-executing js functions) and when r.js runs it puts them in, but then prints 'define("templates", [ "cdjs-helpers", "_", "marionette-dust", "dust-date-helper" ], function() {});' straight afterwards; with them outside the function block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed it. In your require config file (as it says in the docs, and I mention above in my reply) only put shim references to other shim modules.

I called my script from the paths but because it had dependencies I put those in the shim and that's where it broke.

TL:DR; Call your main script with the path entry, then in the main script list your deps in the deps section of the define wrapper...